# Deserializing exception with data generated ksql-datagen utility

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

Generated sample stream from ksql-datagen utility from following schema -

```
{
        "type": "record",
        "name": "users",
        **"namespace": "com.example",**
        "fields": [
        {
        "name": "registertime",
        "type": {
            "type":"long",
            "arg.properties":{
                "range":{"min":1487715775521,"max":1519273364600}
                }
        }
        },
        {
                "name": "userid",
                "type": {
            "type":"string",
            "arg.properties":{"regex":"User_[1-9][0-2]"}
        }
        },
        {
                "name": "regionid",
                "type": {
            "type":"string",
            "arg.properties":{"regex":"Region_[1-9]"}
        }
        },
        {
                "name": "gender",
                "type": {
            "type":"string",
            "arg.properties":{
            "options":["MALE","FEMALE","OTHER"]
            }
        }
        }
]}
```

while checked for versions, it still picks "io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas" schema -

`curl "http://localhost:8081/subjects/test-user-value/versions/1"`

{"subject":"test-user-value","version":1,"id":4,"schema":"{"type":"record","name":"KsqlDataSourceSchema",**"namespace":"io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas"**,"fields":[{"name":"registertime","type":["null","long"],"default":null},{"name":"userid","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"regionid","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"gender","type":["null","string"],"default":null}]}"}

Got following error while tried to consume with Kafka-streams API -

> Exception in thread
>   "PageView-Users-Stream-Join-eg-1dc610a3-c9d9-4c1e-b5eb-910e4bc74826-StreamThread-1"
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Deserialization
>   exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error. If you
>   would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a
>   deserialization error, please set the
>   default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately. at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:80)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.maybeUpdateTimestamp(RecordQueue.java:160)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:101)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:124)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:711)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:995)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:833)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:777)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:747)
>   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException:
>   Error deserializing Avro message for id 4 Caused by:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find
>   **class io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas.KsqlDataSourceSchema specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a
>   SpecificRecord.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered at https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/980

> Datagen always defines the namespace as `io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas`. See [confluentinc/ksql#1906](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1906)

There are now [other ways](https://www.confluent.io/blog/easy-ways-generate-test-data-kafka) to generate test data into Kafka, too.